# Splitting a database (ms access)

Tags: ms-access

Right now I have a database with 4 forms. Two of them are used to add/modify table entries, and two of them are used to generate reports based on the tables. What I would like to do is have two copies of the database. One of them would have all 4 forms, and the other one would have the 2 forms to generate reports. I was wondering if this is possible to do? I also want the info that is modified/edited/deleted in the one database to show up in the other. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried link tables?

Answer (score 0):

Use the *wizard* to split the database into two: One with data (*backend*), one with forms and reports (*frontend*).

Then make two copies of the frontend. In the first copy, delete the two forms, in the other copy, delete the two other forms.

For both frontends, go to database tools and select *Repair and Compact*.

Answer (score 0):

Wizard can be use to split database into front end and back end.Front end with forms and reports and backend with tables.

In front end delete the form as require.